# cat: -: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: cat

I want to add some text to a file.

Using the following command:

```
$ cat > file
```

And getting the following error:

```
cat: -: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

What is happening? how to debug this?

Comment: Try running this into the same terminal `perl -MFcntl -e 'fcntl STDIN, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN, F_GETFL, 0) & ~O_NONBLOCK'`

Comment: This solved the issue ^^ Thanks a lot. Can you explain please?

Comment: That is turning the non-blocking mode back off (to normal). Since `cat` is designed to read in *blocking* mode, it will exit with an error when reading from stdin fails with an EAGAIN error. Now the problem is to determine which program you have run has messed up your terminal ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Below is running fine on RHEL5

```
$ cat > file
```

It appears you are trying to write contents to a file from stdin. Try this

```
$ cat - > file
```

`-` indicates standard input

Comment: Still the same error. I'm running on: 5.4.0-48-generic #52~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 12:50:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux